# Vuejs2: Resend the event for ENTER key

Tags: vuejs2

When in a custom component, I can re-emit click events as `@click="$emit('click')`. Later in the parent, I can directly react to `@click` without having to create a custom event:

```
<!-- In the Parent -->
<custom-component @click="myReaction" ... />
```

How can I re-emit the event for `@keyup` so that I can specifically listen for ENTER via `@keyup.enter="myReaction"` in the parent?  Should it be `@keyup="$emit('keyup')`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `@keyup="$emit('keyup', $event)"` or otherwise you won't be able to get the key code.

You can also rely on the event bubbling for standard DOM events and just use `@keyup.native.enter="myReaction"` in your parent component.

Comment: Once I try and it works. I'll accept it. Thx for the quick response.